# truecrypt - copy without mounting

Tags: mount, truecrypt

I would like to copy files into a truecrypt partition without mounting it or mounting it in a hide way (without another volume displayed in "my computer"). I considered hiding the new volume but it requires admin priv' whice i dont have.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site. I have voted to move this question to superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that by definition.  But if what you want to achieve is to prevent any other user being able to view your files in the mounted TC volume you could change the file permissions to deny read+write access to everyone except yourself.